# SQL Azure + Getting an error 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command..', even after setting ‘MultipleActiveResultSets=True’

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

We are facing some issues with the deployed version of our application on cloud.

Our application is an ASP.NET MVC 3 project with ADO .NET Entity Framework.

According to the msdn blogs, we need to add the parameter ‘MultipleActiveResultSets=True’ (for Entity Framework  with SQL azure) in our database connection string which we have rightly done.

We get the following exception while executing a database query from our application: ‘’There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.”, 
which I guess is very much related to the ‘MultipleActiveResultSets=True’ property.

The application works fine on the local environment with our locally deployed database as well as using the SQL azure database (on local environment).

But when we deploy our application of cloud we get the above mentioned error. It seems that ‘MultipleActiveResultSets=True’ property is not being read from the connection string.

The connection string that I am using is as follows:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="#DBInstanceName#" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:#server#.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=#DBName#;User ID=”UserName#@#server#;Password=”#password#”;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

I am able to connect to SQL Azure database using the above connection string from the locally deployed application without any exceptions. But the same application when deployed on cloud using the same connection string gives me the above mentioned error.

Can you please help us fixing the same?

Comment: Can you verify the connection string using the [**Azure Legacy Portal**](https://windows.azure.com/) or [**Azure Preview Portal**](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) deployment configuration? You could also [setup Remote Access and connect via RDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx) to view the `web.config` directly for each published role.

Answer (score 49):

I've just got the same issue. I has tried setting "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" in Web.config connection - no results.
Finally I've resolved issue by manually editing Connection string directly at Azure Dashboard for the web site - in "Configure" tab there is "Connection strings" settings where you should manually add the "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" string.
After doing that I've got MARS worked finally.

Comment: Also need to restart the web site after editing the connection string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using Visual Studio to manage different environments and the Connection strings was correct. My Test Website was using the web config transform from Visual Studio though my production seems to be hijacked from Azure. I'd like to disable Azure and manage all from Config transforms in VS 2012.

Comment: This works! Apparently, even accessing the web.config file via FTP and setting the `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` does not work. This is the only method that seem to cut it.

Comment: I added it to the DefaultConnection (the only one I have there) in azure manager and it didn't help..

Comment: I thought when deploying via Visual Studio this got updated. It looks like it is not... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help... that did the trick ! I didn't have to restart the site at least now in 2017 :)

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively you can add the "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" to your connection string and update the destination web.config when you are using the Publish feature in Visual Studio. Make sure to select "Use this connection string at runtime (update destination web.config)."[image]

Comment: That was it! Connection string was outdated for some reason.. Thank you!

Comment: this is the way to go, I always use this method and it works flawlessly,

Answer (score 3):

You do have to set multipleresultsets=true in connectionsstring and restart.

Removed answer

> Edit: This is debated! Check comment beneath... I havent had time to
>   investigate...
>
> I think it is already turned on.
>
> I couldn't find a spot-on source but Faisal Mohamood(Program Manager,
>   Entity Framework) states the following back in 2010: "Needless to say,
>   we will make sure that MARS is automatically turned ON for SQL Azure
>   based apps when we get around to releasing the next update to the
>   product." Found it here:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/06/09/remember-to-re-enable-mars-in-your-sql-azure-based-ef-apps.aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in place yet... needed to add MultipleActiveResultSets=True to the Azure web site's connection string, as described by 'irium'

Answer (score 3):

We're on the new Azure portal and had this problem as well. MARS worked on all local dev environments, but threw the same nasty exception on Azure. We verified that the connection string in the physical web.config file deployed to Azure contained `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` but it didn't seem to be honored by the application. Ultimately what worked was going to the app service instance > settings > data connections, and deleting the data connection of the same name as the one in question in the web.config. My guess is that the one that Azure stores trumps the one in the deployed web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning MultipleActiveResultSets in code.   Is it not read or is is not working?

[SqlConnectionStringBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.multipleactiveresultsets.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, but i solved MultipleActiveResultSets=True in the connection string from Publish assistant, as irium