# Intermittent error with EF Core: The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have an ASP.Net Core application that uses EF Core.

I use ASP.Net Identity and share the same DBContext for my app's entities.

I have set my connection string to an Azure SQL database to have MultipleActiveResultSet=True.

It works for a day or two, but eventually it fails with the error:

> The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets.

I don't think MARS is the real issue since it worked for the first two days it was up.

I am using ASP.Net Core's built-in DI to set my DbContext.

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(appDbContextConnectionString));
```

My understanding is that the default lifetime for the DbContext above is Transient (per web request).

Is it alright to share the same DBContext with ASP.Net Identity or should I have a separate one for my app's entities, pointed to the same DB?

I don't know if this is an issue with EF Core, ASP.Net Core or with SQL Azure configuration.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6491 What does he mean by "Does the middleware have a scope per request?"

Comment: can you share the code where you inject or create your db context?

Comment: You might want to check if your connection string with "MultipleActiveResultSet=True" is actually used at runtime. Just a guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690453/sql-azure-getting-an-error-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-wit

Comment: _DbContext_ is not thread safe. Make sure that multiple threads are not using the same context instance. Anytime you call an `async` method in _EF_ the call **MUST** be awaited before making any other call into _EF_.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue and I found that the problem was that I missed an await statement in front of my method.

```
FetchStuffFromDBAsync();
```

Became:

```
await FetchStuffFromDBAsync();
```

And the problem was gone.

Answer (score 6):

`MultipleActiveResultSets=True` need to add in connection string.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Comment: Can you give more info on **why** it needs to be added though? Especially if it's intermittent and a new transient connection is created per request anyway

Comment: It can make your query too slow. You have to be hesitant about using this.

Answer (score 3):

> Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that works with SQL
>   Server to allow the execution of multiple batches on a single
>   connection. When MARS is enabled for use with SQL Server, each command
>   object used adds a session to the connection.

The MARS feature is disabled by default.

You can enable it like below.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" +   
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +  
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

[Special Considerations When Using MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets#special-considerations-when-using-mars)

Answer (score 1):

I kept running into this issue too, and setting `MultipleActiveResultSet=True` in the connection string didn't do much.

My db configuration in `Startup.cs` is very similar to what you have:

```
 services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
         .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly("MyProject")),
            ServiceLifetime.Transient
         );
```

It turned out that I was getting

> The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets

because I had several async db queries accessing the same entities. So one db query would retrieve an entity, and a second would have included the same entity through EF Core's new `Include` method. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46164203/4336725

The reason I had several async db queries was because EF Core does not currently support lazy loading (unlike EF 6). https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3797

My workaround was to define several `IQueryable`s with different explicit `Include()` and `ThenInclude()`.

Answer (score -1):

Remove "Connection Timeout" setting from your connection string.

Comment: Can you please explain why?