# Getting "The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets" in a ForEach with async-await

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach, async-await, dapper

I have the following code using Dapper.SimpleCRUD :

```
var test = new FallEnvironmentalCondition[] {
    new FallEnvironmentalCondition {Id=40,FallId=3,EnvironmentalConditionId=1},
    new FallEnvironmentalCondition {Id=41,FallId=3,EnvironmentalConditionId=2},
    new FallEnvironmentalCondition {Id=42,FallId=3,EnvironmentalConditionId=3}
};
test.ToList().ForEach(async x => await conn.UpdateAsync(x));
```

With this code, I am getting following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets

I don't understand I am `await`ing each update so why am I getting this error.

Note: I have no control on the connection string so I can't turn MARS on.

Comment: In your connection string, be sure to set  MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

Comment: @pmbAustin I am trying to avoid that because I am not in control of the connection string.

Comment: In my case I was missing an await on a method call

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That code starts a Task for each item in the list, but does not wait for the each task to complete before starting the next one. Inside each Task it waits for the update to complete.  Try

```
 Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ForEach(async i => await Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)));
```

Which is equivalent to

```
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList() )
    {
        var task = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now));
    }
```

If you're in a non-async method you will have to Wait(), not await each task.  EG

```
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList() )
    {
        var task = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now));
        //possibly do other stuff on this thread
        task.Wait(); //wait for this task to complete
    }
```

Comment: This helped me! Was (stupidly I might say) trying to access DB in a non-async method.

Comment: The answer below by @RafaelReis mentions the actual cause and provides a solution that does not require delays! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 80):

You need to add attribute `MultipleActiveResultSets` in connection string and set it to true to allow multiple active result sets.

```
 "Data Source=MSSQL1;" & _  
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _  
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Read more at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets

Comment: I am trying to avoid that because I am not in control of the connection string.

Comment: In that case you should use non-async method to update your entities in a sequential manner.

Comment: Why doesn't `await`ing help?

Comment: Because your program will execute the update command in multiple threads which would require simultaneous access to connection.

Comment: Read this documentation on async programming with Ado.net  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming

Comment: this worked so well.  I converted my linq code to stored procedures but ran in the multiple active resultset error.  I added MultipleActiveResultSets=True to the end of my connection string and my code worked.  I am using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync() to access my resultset

Answer (score 33):

The problem is the **ForEach** method ***is not*** an asynchronous method. It ***will not*** await the Task returned by your lambda. Running that code will fire every task and not wait for completion of any of them.

General point: marking a lambda as async does not make a synchronous method you pass it into behave asynchronously.

Solution: you will need to use a foreach loop which awaits the tasks' completion.

eg: foreach (var x in xs) await f(x);

You can wrap that in a helper method if you prefer.

(I know it's an old question, but I don't think it was clearly answered)

Answer (score 6):

MARS has some limitations and also a non-zero overhead. You can use the following helpers to make the updates sequential:

```
public static async Task WhenAllOneByOne<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> process)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
        await process(item);
}

public static async Task<List<U>> WhenAllOneByOne<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task<U>> transform)
{
    var results = new List<U>();

    foreach (var item in source)
        results.Add(await transform(item));

    return results;
    // I would use yield return but unfortunately it is not supported in async methods
}
```

So your example would turn into

```
await test.WhenAllOneByOne(conn.UpdateAsync);
```

I usually call the second helper instead of `Task.WhenAll`, as follows:

```
await Task.WhenAll(source.Select(transform)); // not MARS-safe
await source.WhenAllOneByOne(transform); // MARS-safe
```