# Enabling Multiple Active Result Sets using Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

I'm using Dapper with asp.net core and I'm trying to enable Multiple Active Result

Did anyone managed to enable MARS using Dapper?

I tried to append to the connection `"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"` but with no effect.

[Enabling Multiple Active Result Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets)

The error that I'm getting is

> InvalidOperationException: The connection does not support
>   MultipleActiveResultSets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163437/getting-the-connection-does-not-support-multipleactiveresultsets-when-using-dapp     Any help?

Comment: @MatthewEvans thanks, I've already checked that answer. The difference is that instead of a foreach I'm using a middleware that is logging all the request and response details. I'm not sure if Task.Delay(1000) is a good solution.

Comment: Are you able to make MARS work, it has nothing to do with Dapper but still why was it failing, why can't you enable it, did you discover, are you using Sql Server as database or something else

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only slight connection Dapper has to MARS is when using the overlapped async API to issue multiple in-flight operations with `ExecuteAsync`, *and have told it that you want to* by configuring `Pipelined` to `true` on `CommandDefinition`. Other than that: Dapper **doesn't care** about MARS. If you enable it on your connection: it will be enabled; if you don't: it won't. The key thing that won't work without MARS is: using an **unbuffered** query (`Query<T>(...buffered: false)`) and then issuing additional operations *inside* that query. But that is usually avoidable by simply: *not doing that*. You can also enable MARS on your connection string, but frankly I generally advice *against* that.

So: Dapper has no explicit controls related to MARS *except for* in the case of `ExecuteAsync` with `Pipelined` enabled.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I have got a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/511021/1559611), which explains the same concept well. The way I understood this functionality is primarily meant for connected architecture to enable execution of more queries on every unit of result fetched. On other hand it has nothing to do with Multiple result sets, which is a default behavior

Answer (score 3):

`MultipleActiveResultSets=True` is an ADO.Net configuration, it has nothing to do with the Dapper, it is meant to carry out overlapped batch operation on a Single live connection, check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510899/multipleactiveresultsets-true-or-multiple-connections/511021#511021) for more information.

In case your aim is to receive multiple result sets in a single execution, then that has nothing to do with MARS and is enabled by default. Doing it using Dapper you need to use `QueryMultiple` to fetch the `GridReader`, which can help fetch multiple result sets, check [Dapper Query Multiple](https://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple). In plain vanilla ADO.Net for same purpose, you need to use `DataReader.NextResult` for the connected architecture and Dataset for disconnected architecture for fetching multiple result sets

Comment: Note: `GridReader` is for querying multiple **consecutive** result sets on a single operation, which is completely orthogonal to MARS; you can use either, neither, or both

Comment: @MarcGravell if a query / proc execution generates multiple consecutive result set then to fetch it we need MARS enabled and `QueryMultiple`, what is other use case beside it. Especially since multiple results can have completely different schema, so none of the other API fits in

Comment: " then to fetch it we need MARS enabled" - no, completely incorrect, sorry; that is **not** what MARS means. MARS is for issuing two *overlapped* queries, i.e. you issue query A, fetch 1 row (of 96, say), and then issue another query/command B, then look at row 2 of A, etc - the key point here: you issue a second command while an existing command *is still being iterated*

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for the clarification this means, we don't need to do anything special for the fetching multiple result sets just use the correct API, MARS enabled / disabled as no role. Is there a good example to review ?